# Find the base 2 logarithm of the next power of 2 of an integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I've run into this a bunch, and it seems like there should be a better way to do this. I'd like to use bit twiddling to accomplish something equivalent to the following:

```
uint8_t nextlog(uint32_t n) {
  return (uint8_t) ceil(log2(n)) + 1;
}
```

Example usage:

```
nextlog(0) -> undefined
nextlog(1) == 1
nextlog(3) == 3  // 0b11 -{next power 2}-> 0b100 -{log2+1}-> 3
nextlog(32) == 6 // 0b00100000 -{log2+1}-> 6
nextlog(71) == 8 // 0b01000111 --> 0b10000000 -> 8
```

The best I've come up with is to combine the "Round up to the next highest power of 2" and "Finding integer log base 2 of an integer" from the well-known [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) reference. I suppose it's also worth noting that `__builtin_clz` could help accomplish the latter part of the question.

Comment: Why the `clz` solution is not good for you?

Comment: @EugeneSh. it is. In fact, the implementation with doubles is sufficient for my purposes. However, I'd like to know if there's an implementation that doesn't effectively waste a bunch of effort identifying the next highest power of 2 and then throwing that away.

Comment: I don't understand. `32 - __builtin_clz(n)` is solving your problem. What are you asking?

Comment: @EugeneSh. `32 - __builtin_clz(n)` isn't actually solving my problem. I'm not rounding down in the float implementation, I'm intentionally rounding up. I'm trying to find the number of bits a given maximum value will fit in.

Comment: Why isn't that combination of bit-twiddling hacks good enough for you?    In other words, what measure are you using to define "best"?

Comment: @Peter if I understand you correctly, I already answered that question in my first comment. To expand: it seems like a waste of effort to calculate the next highest power of 2 when you could even do something like `uint8_t b=32-__builtin_clz(n);return b+!!(n&~(1 << b))`.

Comment: Sounds like you actually want `33 - __builtin_clz(n-1)`, except that that doesn't work for `n=1` (because `__builtin_clz(0)` is undefined).

Comment: Float? Your function is working with `int`s..

Comment: `log2` operates on doubles in C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Mark Dickinson's comment, the obvious solution with a single branch is as follows:

```
uint8_t nextlog(uint32_t n) {
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  return 33 - __builtin_clz(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `32 - clz(x)`, despite your claim to the contrary.

You claim that log<sub>2</sub> 0b100 is 3, this is the error in your math.  The correct answer is 2.

It's not in the "bit twiddling hacks" page, but I found this:

```
int clz(uint32_t x) {
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    return 32 - popcount(x);
}

int popcount(uint32_t x) {
    x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

Note that I'm sure that the performance is somewhat terrible, compared to what should be little more than `ffs` on x86.

See: http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Leading%20Zero%20Count

Comment: Re: your first two comments, I tried to say I could use clz, not necessarily in isolation. You're right, I meant `log2+1`

Comment: Then why not just use 31 - clz instead of 32 - clz?